# Javascript documentation for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is there any documentation for customizing Kibana via javascript?
I'm having so much trouble figuring it out without it.

Again, I'm not talking about documentation for json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation of the Kibana code beyond the commit descriptions in the github repository of the open source project: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana and the occasional comments that the developer left.

Kibana is built on top of standard frameworks and libraries that are well documented.
These include:

- https://angularjs.org/
- http://www.fullscale.co/elasticjs/
- http://requirejs.org/
- http://jquery.com/
- http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
- http://www.flotcharts.org/

(find the exhaustive list of dependencies in the https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/src/vendor folder)

Two important parts of Kibana that are worth mentioning are:

1. The services listed under https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/src/app/services

These angular services power the application by connecting it with Elasticsearch and providing the glue between most of the components. The dashboard.js file controls loading the json files into the application. The filterSrv.js and querySrv.js files control the interaction with Elasticsearch.

1. The panels listed under https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/src/app/services

Panels are independant angular controllers that can be added, configured, moved around in Kibana. They are great examples of standalone angular controllers. I would recommend tweaking existing panels as a way to understand more about how Kibana works.